# Installing Pillow on Python

Tags: python, libraries, python-imaging-library

I am trying to instal **Pillow-2.7.0-cp27-none-win32.whl** on my Python **2.7.2**:

So I open a comand prompt and type:

```
pip install Pillow-2.7.0-cp27-none-win32.whl
```

But I get the following message:

Pillow-2.7.0-cp27-none-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this plataform.

Edited: I am on a windows 7 professional 64bit service pack one

So what now?

Comment: What OS are you on? It looks link you are trying to install a windows 32 bit version of Pillow

Comment: windows 7 professional 64bit service pack one

Comment: Have you tried the simple `pip install Pillow`?

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Pillow page in pypi.python.org: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/
2. Pick a distribution for your operating system. 64-bit Windows is suffixed **win_amd64.whl** if you need exact package, but generic

   pip install Pillow should be enough

Please refer to [Pillow installation guide](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/installation.html).

Answer (score 0):

I am almost certain you are trying to install 32-bit Pillow with a 64-bit Python. This is unrelated to windows being 64-bit.

Try this if you really need 2.7 instead of the latest pillow:

```
pip install "https://pypi.python.org/packages/cp27/P/Pillow/Pillow-2.7.0-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl#md5=f39617259e9e3d2ef5d885576fc0acda"
```

Unless you have a good reason though, do as others are saying and just follow the installation guide or do

```
pip install pillow
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the 64-bit version of Pillow using the 64-bit wheel.